# Chow groups of arithmetic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Given an arithmetic surface $S$, I would like to know the following properties of its first and second Chow groups $CH^1(S), CH^2(S)$:

1. Are they finitely generated? If so, what is the rank?
2. What is the size of the torsion subgroup?

Comment: The example you gave at the end doesn't seem to be homogeneous.  Is that intentional?